# jQuery hide show element logic

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list of images that I want to have text appear next to them when they are clicked on. I have set the opacity of the image as 0.5 in the default state and when a user hovers over the image, the opacity goes to full or 1.

Now I want the opacity of the image to be at 1 as long as the text box is open.

You can get a better idea by [viewing this fiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/zQxuR/)

I have tried this for my javascript but its not working:

```
$('.team-text .close').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('.team-text').hide();
});


$('.team-member .team-photo, .team-member .bio-button, .team-member-minor .team-photo, .team-member-minor .bio-button').on('click', function(){
  $(this).find('.team-text:visible').hide();
  $(this).find('.team-member img, .team-member-minor img').css('opacity','0.5');
});

$('.team-photo, .bio-button').on('click', function () {
   $('.team-text').hide();
   $(this).prevAll('.team-text:hidden').show();
   $(this).prevAll('.team-member img, .team-member-minor img').css('opacity','1');
});
```

Comment: Which textbox?  I don't see a textbox in the jsfiddle.

Comment: When you click on the image the text box appears.

Comment: You should try this another way...

Use this: opacity: 0.5 directly on the CSS file, and create two clases. Clases for when inactive and for when active. There, you can use addClass when the Bio is active.

Hope I have helped!

Comment: The textbox really isn't a textbox, its just a label.  This is a textbox: <input type="text" />.  Sorry, I am being picky, but the textbox term you used is what initially confused me.

Comment: What's `.team-member` supposed to be? This selector matches no elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following to the `.on('click')` piece for `.team-photo,.bio-button`:

```
$('img').removeAttr('style');
$(this).find('img').css({opacity:1});
```

This removes any style tag on the existing images (added by changing their opacity), and then setting the opacity of the clicked `img` to 1.

To reset the opacity on closing the text portion, just `removeAttr('style');` on the click of `.close`:

```
$('img').removeAttr('style');
```

I think this is what you want. I also updated your jsFiddle.

Comment: LifeInTheGrey, that does exactly what I am looking for. And I did not know that you could remove an attribute with jquery! I thought you could just change the css. Removing the attribute makes more sense. Should I post the updated code or does just having it on jsFiddle help?

Comment: oh I think you're fine, the jsFiddle provides a good reference.

Comment: I beg to disagree. I don't think this answer solves all the issues in your code. For instance, your `click` event handlers are redundant and you are not making any good usage of the CSS classnames. You have ended up with an overly complicated code for such an easy task

Comment: Well then what be an easier way?

Comment: @MGDTech, check Nick's answer for starters. Even though it is not perfectly correct it is driven there

Answer (score 2):

Apply a css class (e.g. `active`) to the `.team-member` div on your "active" state, that way you don't have to manually set the opacity for each item. This also makes things cleaner and more maintainable for the future.

EDIT: 
I've changed the class names per @Alexander's suggestion below. http://jsfiddle.net/Lh6xU/ Here's his [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh6xU/)

**css**

```
.team-member-minor img {
 opacity:.5; /* the default state for images; no need for jQuery */
}
.team-text {
display:none; 
}
/* "active" class */
.team-member-minor.active img {
opacity:1;
}

.active .team-text {
display:inline;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.team-member-minor').on('click', function(){
     $(this)
      .addClass('active')
      .siblings('.team-member-minor')
      .removeClass('active');
}

// if a user "closes" the textbox, reset our team member

$('.team-text .close').click(function () {
   $(this).parent('.team-text').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. That seems to make more sense. If you noticed in my css I did have the opacity set for the images. However, I can't seem to get your javascript to work as planned.

Comment: That's because there's no `.team-member`, but `.team-member-minor`. And the `.close` should remove the `active` classname from `.team-member-minor`. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh6xU/) :)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle Alexander. I'll reference it in my answer, and reflect it the class names there.